# C# class in folder and needs to call on class in another folder

Tags: c#, class, reference, xna, directory

I have a folder named `StartUp`, it holds the beginning classes and are loaded up first in the program. I want to access another folder named `OverAll`, it holds classes that will be used over the whole game. I want to take from `OverAll` a class named `Mouses`, and transfer it over the any other class in `StartUp`.

**EDIT:** 10:00 12/7/2013

This is the Files and Folders, lets take for example that `Mouses.cs` has an `public int thing = 1;` and I want it to move to `TitleScreen.cs`, what do I wright to allow `TitleScreen.cs` to view/edit that int?

I can access all classes in `Game1.cs` by calling on there folder then the class (Ex. `OverAll.Mouses.ect = 1;`) and vic-versa.

[image: Files and folders]

`OverAll.Mouses.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Lover__Regret
{
    class Mouses
    {
        public int thing = 1;
    }
}
```

`StartUp.TitleScreen.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Love__Regret.StartUp
{
    class TitleScreen
    {
        public static void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
        //Want to call thing here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "take a class and transfer it over"? Some code might help illustrate the idea.

Comment: @CodeCaster I will update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `thing` field in `Mouses` is not a static field. That means you need to have an instance reference to `Mouses` inside `TitleScreen` in order to be able to access it.

You said that in `Game1.cs` you already have references to instances. So, what I suggest is to do the following:

1. The `Update` method in `TitleScreen` should *not* be static. You need to Update a specific `TitleScreen` instance. So remove the static keyword.
2. Create a constructor for `TitleScreen` that takes a instance of `Mouses` and a field to store that instance:

   private Mouses _mouseHandler;

   public TitleScreen(Mouses mouseHandler)
   {
       _mouseHandler = mouseHandler;
   }
3. Then, in the `Update` method call something like this:

   Console.WriteLine(_mouseHandler.thing); // or whatever you want to do with fields from `Mouses`
4. Now, when you construct `TitleScreen` in `Game1.cs`, create it like this, passing a `Mouses` instance:

   // create the mouses instance (e.g.: Mouses mouses = new Mouses())
   TitleScreen screen = new TitleScreen(mouses);

Most of programming is not done via static classes/methods (that would be procedural-ish programming). You instead need to create instances of your classes.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was hoping of bypassing the main class (`Game1.cs`) and not have to use it. Since I know how to reference classes but wanted to use the most minimal code, witch means I will have to do the same for every class that is like ie. `Credits`, `Options`, `TitleScreen` and any other class that needs the `Mouses` class. Skipping the main class would have saved about 20 lines of code but I was, again trying for the least amount of code.

Comment: I have figered out why I was not able to access the other folder `OverAll`, there is a bug in the program. I don't know were it is but creating a new project and making 2 folders and adding a class in each I was able to access the other class by simply doing: `private OverAll.Mouses mouses;` and then was able to access Mouses's information and change it at will. I don't know what is wrong in the other project.

Comment: Well, you'd better try and write maintainable code even if it's "just" 20 lines of code more. What I mean by that is that your code shouldn't be all static. At least use the Singleton pattern if you don't want to "mess" around with instances :)